# Python K means clustering Array

Tags: python, arrays, k-means

i'm looking for a way to segment a 2D array in n clusters with python. I want to use the K means method but I haven't found any code. I tryed with the k-means of the sklearn library but i haven't understood how to use it properly.

Answer (score 3):

From http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

#this is your array with the values
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
               [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])


#This function creates the classifier
#n_clusters is the number of clusters you want to use to classify your data
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)

#you can see the labels with:
print kmeans.labels_

# the output will be something like:
#array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
# the values (0,1) tell you to what cluster does every of your data points correspond to

#You can predict new points with
kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [4, 4]])

#array([0, 1], dtype=int32)

#or see were the centres of your clusters are
kmeans.cluster_centers_
#array([[ 1.,  2.],
#     [ 4.,  2.]])
```

Comment: Yes i have already tryed it, but with kmeans.labels_ it give me only a 1D array, i want that it give me and array like input array and each element is changed to the number of the cluster in which it was assigned

Answer (score 1):

In general, to use a model from sklearn you have to:

1. import it: `from sklearn.cluster import KMeans`
2. Initialize an object representing the model with the chosen parameters, `kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)`, as an example.
3. Train it with your data, using the `.fit()` method:  `kmeans.fit(points)`. Now the object `kmeans` has all the data related to your trained model in its attributes. As an example, `kmeans.labels_` corresponds to an array with the labels of each one of the points used to train the model.
4. Use the`.predict(new_points)` method to get the label of the closest cluster to a point or an array of points.

You can get the all the attributes from the kmeansalgorithm page:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html